# Nexus 7 randomly reboots and resets date to 1999

Tags: nexus-7, date-and-time

Twice now my Nexus 7 has randomly rebooted while it was charging and the date was changed to December 31, 1999 and the time has been changed; this time it was set six hours ahead. Does anyone know what's going on and how to stop it?

Update: It just happened again today, 4/28/13. This time the time was set 2 hours ahead. It's been charging every time this has happened.

Edit:

- I use the original charger and cable. However, the charging port is a
  little bent and I can't do a data connection to a PC, and it can
  be a little hard to get it to charge sometimes.
- I do not use any docks.
- My Android version is 4.2.2
- I updated the Android version myself using ClockWorkMod Recovery as I am rooted.
- I have 63 apps installed.
- I do not use task killers.
- I have not yet done a factory reset since I won't be able to re-root (see note about charger above) and it would take quit a while to re-download everything since I only have internet occasionally. I will do a factory reset only if it's the last resort.

This isn't too big of a problem, just annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have N7 too. I never heard or read about anything like this. It can be faulty battery or charging circuit, but it can be just SW problem.

First, please, add some important details to your question:

- Did you use original charger?
- Did you use original USB cable?
- Did you use original dock?
- What android version do you have?
- Do you have this version out of box from the first day (from factory) or did you get it as OTA update or did you update it yourself?
- How many apps do you have installed?
- Do you use any task killer?
- Did you try reset to factory defaults?

Comment: Added the details you wanted.

Comment: Do you mean by "the charging port is a little messed up" that the micro USB connector on your Nexus 7 is dirty and has a poor contact?

Comment: The metal "frame" part of it has come apart at the joint and is a little loose, and the one of the gold contacts got bent up and I had to flatten it.

Comment: Ouch, I think that damaged micro USB connector on your Nexus 7 can be culprit of your problem. You can check this theory: rent the dock from friend and try to charge through the dock's pogo pins, I bet that everything will be all right.

Comment: I don't think I know anyone who has one but I'll check. I am also planning on replacing the port anyways, just haven't yet.

Comment: Haven't fixed it yet, but while jiggling the charger trying to get it to work out reset again. Pretty sure that's the problem. Thanks